# Error al ejecutar archivo Node.js en SSL

Tags: nodejs, linux, ssl

Estoy intentando montar un servidor SSL con NODE.JS en una instancia Amazon Linux 2.

El package.js es este:

```
{
  "name": "Prueba",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Prueba",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mysql": "^2.5.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

El JS es este:

```
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello there !');
});

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo me devuelve este error:

> fs.js:549   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
>   stringToFlags(flags), mode);
>                    ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/privkey.pem'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
>       at Object. (/home/ec2-user/index.js:9:23)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
>       at startup (node.js:139:18)

He cambiado los permisos de

> /etc/letsencrypt/live/

con chmod 755, pero el error continua

Alguien sabe que puede estar faltando?. Gracias!

Comment: Lo mas básico: comprueba que **todos los directorios** son legibles y **accesibles** por el usuario que ejecuta `node`.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma por tu respuesta, mis conocimientos son muy basicos. ¿Como compruebo eso?

Comment: Si ingresa en el directorio sin problemas (por favor quita el domino del comentario). Gracias

Comment: Pues ya me quedo sin opciones, la verdad. El error es claro, `Error: EACCES: permission denied`. *Huele* a tema de permisos desde lejos :-(

Comment: Intenta ejecutar tu servidor con un usuario que sea sudo. Ya que para leer los certificados desde /etc se necesita esos permisos.

Comment: Hola @EugeniBejan, estoy haciendolo a traves de ssh con el usuario que me da amazon que estimo es el de mas permisos, no se como hacerlo con otro usuario. Si me podes ayudar en ese punto lo intentaria gustosamente. Gracias!

Comment: Es tan simple como hacer sudo server.js.

Comment: `chmod -R 755 /tu/carpeta` porque o si no, lo que haya debajo queda igual sin permisos

Comment: ¿¡ Pero **en serio** hay gente que sugiere que **ejecutes un programa como `sudo`** !? Solo espero, por el bien de la humanidad, que esos comentarios sean *de coña* ...

Comment: Gracias a todos!, pude resolver el inconveniente ejecutando la solucion de @Alfabravo: sudo chmod -R 755 /etc/letsencrypt/, no se si sera seguro pero asi se solucionó. Ahora se presento un nuevo problema que describo en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230733/error-al-arrancar-script-nodejs-https Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio por favor indícalo como respuesta a la pregunta y luego, márcala como aceptada. Así los demás sabrán qué te funcionó

Comment: @EugeniBejan La solución nunca es escalarle los privilegios a la ejecución. Siempre será dar el mínimo de permisos al usuario que ejecuta nuestra aplicación.

Comment: @Alfabravo Tendrias que colocarla como respuesta para poder hacer lo que me dices. Actualmente solo esta como comentario. Me quedo con la inquietud de si darle permisos 755, a la carpeta '/etc/letsencrypt/' es seguro. Gracias

Comment: @Alfabravo realmente yo me había encontrado con ese problema y ejecutándolo con sudo lo resolví, pero por lo visto no es la mejor solución. Gracias por tu comentario, siempre es bueno aprender algo más

Comment: @EugeniBejan ejecutar con sudo es darle al proceso, privilegios de superusuario. Si algo de lo que se ejecuta allí tiene una vulnerabilidad, tienen acceso a todo lo que tiene acceso el superusuario. En general, procura darle a tus procesos/servicios el mínimo de permisos necesarios para funcionar.