# Error al arrancar script NodeJs HTTPS

Tags: nodejs, linux, ssl, https

Tengo una instancia EC2 con Linux 2 y estoy intentando correr el siguiente servidor https en NodeJS:

```
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mi-dominio.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello there !');
});

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

Al momento de arrancarlo ejecutando `node index.js` devuelve el siguiente error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/index.js:28:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Alguien sabe a que puede deberse el error?. GRacias!

Comment: el puerto 80 esta ocupado trata de cambiar el puerto, seguramente tienes apache2 o nginx instalado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es muy posible que se deba a que no tienes permiso para usar el puerto 80. Los puertos bajos (hasta el 1024) normalmente no permiten su uso por defecto en sistemas Linux relativamente recientes. Sólo a través de paquetes como los servidores HTTP es posible normalmente (o metiéndose con la configuración pero no es recomendado si no se tiene claro qué hacer).

Una opción es crear un usuario con permisos mínimos que ejecute tu Node y pueda usar el puerto 80. [Este instructivo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) es completo (sobre debian-based) pero las instrucciones básicas a ejecutar son estas:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/local/bin/node
sudo npm install pm2 -g
pm2 start tuapp.js
```

Otra es configurar para usar Node.js a través de Nginx.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Alfabro, al hacer: sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin, me devuelve el siguiente error sudo: apt-get: command not found, olvide aclarar que estoy usando Linux 2 en Amazon. Gracias!

Comment: SIgnifica que es una distribución sin ese paquete apt-get. Podríás revisar qué equivalente hay, si lo logro, espero revisar en un rato.

Comment: Creo que se utiliza YUM. Gracias!

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, @JackNavaRow !! :D

Comment: probe el puerto 1024 y funciona correctamente, no asi el 1023.

Comment: @Patricio entonces sí es de permisos...

Answer (score 3):

El error dice "***El puerto 80 esta ocupado***":

> Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80

Los programas mas comunes que lo usan son los siguientes:

- Nginx
- Apache, Apache2
- Skype

Lo que se recomienda  es usar otro puerto y con la ayuda de servidores como nginx o apache2 hacer el redireccionado

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!, Skype y Apache no tengo instalado en el servidor, Nginx no se, no lo conozco, estoy usando una instancia Amazon Ec2 linux 2. Pero no es solo el puerto 80, hice una pruyeba y son todos los puertos por debajo de 1024, 1023 ya da ese error como indica @Alfabro. Saludos!

Comment: `services nginx status` o `services apache2 status`

Comment: Ambos me devuelven: -bash: services: command not found

Comment: Si pongo en singular service, me dice: Unit nginx.service could not be found. y Unit apache2.service could not be found.

Comment: es service , estas entrando por ip publica?

Comment: Estoy entrando con Putty por SSH. Gracias